# Foreach para matriz

Tags: php

Tenho uma matriz e preciso saber como posso fazer o `foreach` e saber o tamanho total da matriz.

```
$matriz = array();

$matriz[0][1] = '01';
$matriz[0][2] = '02';
$matriz[1][1] = '11';
$matriz[1][2] = '12';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para percorrer o `array`, que é multidimensional, é necessário percorrer também os *subarrays*:

```
$matriz = array();

$matriz[0][1] = '01';
$matriz[0][2] = '02';
$matriz[1][1] = '11';
$matriz[1][2] = '12';

foreach ($matriz as $itens) {
    foreach ($itens as $item) {
        echo $item . "\n";
    }
}
```

Para saber o total de itens, você pode usar o [`count`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php), porém por se tratar de um `array` multidimensional, use `count` em conjunto com o [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php), assim vai retornar a quantidade de itens que cada *subarray* tem, para somá-los, use o [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-sum.php):

```
echo "Total: " . array_sum(array_map("count", $matriz)) . "\n"; // 4
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/ZWEBp6)</kbd>